# Is emmeans trt.vs.ctrl a two-sided test?

Tags: emmeans

I am performing a dunnett comparison after a glm.nb with an interaction using emmeans. I have a reviewer asking whether the test I performed is two tailed or right tailed. I cannot seem to find a clear answer so far for this method.

Is there a way that I can specify this?
OR
Is there a different post-hoc method that I can use to specify the alternative?

Context:
My data is 7 different treatments, each with four levels of concentration which includes a zero level for concentration (a solvent control). I found that glm.nb fits my data the best through various testing of different models. I have a random variable (date) that accounts for some of the variability in the responses. The response is the number of times a given behaviour was observed in an arthropod.

Thanks,
Mike

I have done:
glmer.nb.fooreturn %>% emmeans(~ conc|odour) -> emm_int
contrast(emm_int, "trt.vs.ctrl", ref = "0", type = "response", adjust="D")

Comment: I found that I can do this: summary(as.glht(contrast(emm_int, "trt.vs.ctrl", ref = "0", type = "response", adjust="D"), alternative = 'greater')) ... but is this correct? Also it changes adjustment method to single-step, can I change this?

Comment: Then I discovered this: summary1 <- emmeans(mod1, specs = trt.vs.ctrl ~ conc|odour)
summary(summary1)
test(summary1, side = ">",adjust = "tukey")
confint(summary1, by = "odour") which gives sidak adjusted p-values but I am worried how many ways there are to get around to my answer and which one is correct (or most correct).

Comment: By default, the tests are two-sided, and you should not change that less you specified a particular direction without ever looking at the results.

Comment: Thank you very much @RussLenth Our study is testing if responses are different than controls, and whether there could be concentration-dependent responses. I guess we have an assumption that responses will be greater than controls, but we are not explicit in the manuscript. I agree that my test should be two-tailed. It initially was not clear to me if the contrast code I initially posted above was two-tailed. Cheers, Michael